# C++ Global variables and initialization order

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, global

Let's say, I've got a following simple code:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

// For several reasons this must be a global variable in the project
A a1;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Another stuff
    return 0;
}
```

**A.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class A
{
private:
    // The following works normal if we use simple types like int and etc.
    static std::string myString;

public:
    A();
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"

// This executes after A::A(), so we are losing all the modifyed content
// If we skip the ="test" part, the string is going to be empty
std::string A::myString = "test";

A::A()
{
    // Here myString == ""
    myString += "1";
}
```

The problem is obvious: I cannot use static variables in a constructor of class A in this case as they don't save the changes. Although I need them in order to process some data.

Please, suggest me a solution.

Comment: Your problem is not at all obvious to me. It looks like you code would work, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The problem is it should initialize A::myString before entering A::A(). But it doesn't. Here I'm talking about this kind of design. I need to make A::myString initialize first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to force the initialization of the static to happen **before** the constructor is called. The last time I encountered this problem, the only reliable fix was to wrap the static inside a function.

Change the declaration to a function returning reference to string.

```
static std::string& myString();
```

Change the definition to a function like this:

```
std::string& A::myString() {
     static std::string dummy = "test";
     return dummy;
}
```

Change your constructor to say:

```
myString() += "1";
```

I do not currently have an MSFT compiler handy, so you may have to tweak this a little bit, but this basically forces on-demand initialization of static.

Here is a very short test programming demonstrating how this works:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


std::string& myString() {
     static std::string dummy = "test";
     return dummy;
}

int main(){
    myString() += "1";
    printf("%s\n", myString().c_str());
}
```